# Task scheduling for ASP.NET with access to HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scheduled-tasks, httpcontext

First of all, my aim is to implement task scheduling in which the job is to create an offline HTML file of the current webpage everyday.

I have tried Quartz.NET but it seems unfit because `HttpContext` cannot be accessed by the Job class. As the content of the page highly rely on server side data, and there are lot of client side edits when the offline file is being generated, these could be very complex if no direct access into 'ready-made' `HttpContext`.

Any recommendation and idea for me?

(I'm using earlier version of ASP.NET instead of Core, so `HttpContextAccessor` is not considered either.)

Answer (score 0):

While creating `Job` you have access to HttpContext, you can supply all the information from `HttpContext` to `JobBuilder`.

Code taken from https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

Code is in c#, I hope you would be able to do same in vb.net

```
// define the job and tie it to our DumbJob class

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DumbJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
    .UsingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World!") // key value (put required key and value from HttpContext)
    .UsingJobData("myFloatValue", 3.141f)
    .Build();
```

Here’s a quick example of getting data from the JobDataMap during the job’s execution:

Getting Values from a JobDataMap

```
public class DumbJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

        string jobSays = dataMap.GetString("jobSays");
        float myFloatValue = dataMap.GetFloat("myFloatValue");

        await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync("Instance " + key + " of DumbJob says: " + jobSays + ", and val is: " + myFloatValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The content of the page does always update in accordance to the data from server, and this is the purpose of what I intend to do - see the first paragraph of the question. Therefore, the process of accessing HttpContext should be within the job's execution instead of the initiation of task scheduler. Otherwise, every downloaded file would be exactly the same and it would be meaningless.